# why do I need to use OpenVG in my Android App?

Tags: android, sdk, openvg

I want to scan a fingerprint. Also I have the device SDK provided for the manufacturer and there is an example inside of how to use the functions. When I run the example code suddenly it crashes while saying: "libOpenVG.so not found"

There is nothing in my code with the word "OpenVG". If I really nedd to use that thing, how can I use OpenVG in android studio?

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM?

Comment: I don't think so. In the datasheet there is no reference to any custom ROM, the only thing that it says is the Android Version 4.2.2 (jelly bean)

Comment: Fixed. I searched the Internet and I found something called AndroidVG which is a library with a lot of files. I added them to my Android.mk and named the module "libOpenVG" and that solved the problem